# Name for unique unordered multiset combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, terminology

Given the the following set

```
a1
a2
b1
c1
```

I am looking for the combination like this:

```
{ Ø, a1, a2, b1, c1, a1b1, a2b1, a1b1c1, a2b1c1 }
```

Is there a name for this type of permutation I am looking for? Each sub-group can be combined with each other sub-group but always only one element out of them and their order does not matter.

Comment: There is no $c_2$ in your list.  Also, check to see that you didn't omit combination.

Comment: Thank you @mrtwhs. I missed that one, updated the expected result and checked it one more time.

Comment: I'm still not understanding something.  Why aren't $a_1a_2$ or $a_1c_1$ or lots of other combinations not listed?

Comment: @mrtwhs I agree that we are in a minefield of ambiguity trying to use telepathy on the OP (i.e. the original poster).  My reverse-engineering surmise (*so far*) is that the OP has partitioned the original set into the subsets $\{a1,a2\}, \{b1\}, \{c1\}$.  Then, from each subset, you either take one element, or you skip the subset.  However, even this *attempted telepathy* doesn't explain why $a1c1$ (for example) is missing.

Comment: Also, the OP has not explained what (for example) the expression $a1b1$ signifies.  Is it to be understood that all of the elements are either Real or Complex numbers, and that $a1b1$ signfies $a1 \times b1$?  If not, then what does $a1b1$ signify?